# R ggplot stacked bar chart for time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried following the instructions for question 28557393 but they don't seem to work for me. My data (converted to what I think is a [long table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGVah.png))
I have tried this code

```
ggplot(table_long, aes(x=Year, y=ktoe, fill=factor(energy_type))) +  
geom_col()
```

which looks like [image: This].

or this

```
ggplot(table_long, aes(x = Year, y = ktoe, fill=energy_type)) +  
geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

which looks like this [image: here]. What am I doing wrong?
I have some hope my data is correctly form as

```
table_long %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=ktoe, col=energy_type))
```

Looks roughly like I want the bar chart to look like: [image: geom plot]

Comment: It looks like your variable "ktoe" is a factor or character type and not numeric.  Try converting to numeric with `y=as.numeric(ktoe)` in the `aes` definition and see if that works.

Comment: it will be easier to answer this question if you  provide a reproducible example, see [here0(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make a reproducible example

Comment: what do you get with `str(table_long)`? Similar issue as @Dave2e referred to, but wondering about Year.

Comment: @markhogue    > str(table_long)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 392 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Year       : num  1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 ...
 $ energy_type: chr  "Coal" "Coal" "Coal" "Coal" ...
 $ ktoe       : chr  "14242" "12164" "10602" "10565" ...

Comment: @Dave2e I think you have cracked the most basic problem, it plots something much more like I was expecting now! Thanks for you help. I can't see how to upvote answers, maybe I'm too new?

Comment: @Handschuhe, I am glad you were able to solve your problem.  This is a common problem trying to plot the wrong data type. I am going to flag this question for closure since this is such a common problem and many posted solutions.